# connection was reset when uploading photo laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, apache, mamp

I have a problem while uploading files into my apache server, the navigator keeps showing the message the connection was reset. I've tried with little files (100kb), it works just fine, but when I tried 500kb or more files the connection was reset...

I've already modified my file php.ini to 300M but It didn't work, and I've already restarted my apache server (I'm using mamp)

here's the code I'm using to store the file

```
$file = $request->file('image'); 

$fruit = new fruit;

$imageContent = $file->openFile()->fread($file->getSize());
```

Thank you !!!

Comment: There is something amiss. The `$imageContent` intention we can discuss later. What would be interesting to know is what happens next. How do you get to the View and what are you sending to your View?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant by your question.... I'm sending the code bellow :
{ <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{{ url('FruitCreate') }}" >
 {{ csrf_field() }}
 <input type="text" name='name'>
 <input type="text" name='price'>
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />
 <input type="file" name='image'>
 <select name='quantitytype'>
  <option value='unity'> unity </option>
  <option value='kg'> kg </option>
 </select> 
  
 <button type='submit'> submit </button>
 
?>
  {{ csrf_field() }}


</form>